# expression in ted

Tags: meaning-in-context

You can see this most clearly when you take away someone's watch and you shut them into a bunker, deep underground, for a couple of months. (Laughter) People actually volunteer for this, and they usually come out kind of raving about their productive time in the hole. So, *no matter how atypical these subjects would have to be, they all show the same thing.* They get up just a little bit later every day

as far as I know, *would have to* is used like I would have to do sth if~ in the conditional situation, but I cant understand what the meaning of this expression is in this context.

Comment: What do you mean by *in ted*? Does this come from a TED Talks presentation? If so, can you link to it? I'm assuming that the first paragraph you have is a *quote* and that the second one is your own voice?

Comment: I think it's a bit of a sloppy sentence. It would be better to either substitute 'would have to' with 'must' or to keep 'would have to be' and continue with 'they *would* all show the same thing', i.e. keep the hypothetical aspect consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the part that you are hung up on is the "No matter how atypical these subjects would have to be".

I agree that this is probably not the best way she could say this, but speaking without a script can lead to a less than ideal use of grammar.

The speaker is recognizing that the people (from the previous sentence) who would volunteer to be shut up in a bunker for months are probably **atypical**. This is because normal people wouldn't want to be cut off for the world and by themselves for so long voluntarily. 
To isolate that part as a complete thought in separate sentence:

> These subjects would have to be *very* atypical to volunteer to be put in a bunker for a couple months. Even so, they all showed the same thing.

The speaker seems to be implying that you would expect a variety of results from the volunteers because they are all atypical. I am not sure if that is truly logical.

---

Similar use that makes a little bit more sense to me:

> Sometimes the mafia trains guard dogs to protect their valuable properties. But, no matter how **vicious** these guard dogs would have to be, they all show **friendly** behavior around their owners.

I think this example shows a much clearer explanation of why this sentence structure is used. "Would have to be" has an implied "to protect the valuable property". Meanwhile, vicious and friendly are clearly opposite each other in terms of dog behavior.

Hope this helps!